# Area Based Kolmogorov Smirnov

Tags: kolmogorov-smirnov-test, empirical-cumulative-distr-fn

I have several sets to two ECDFs that I want to compare. I know I can use the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test (and I have) but one set of ECDF is returning statistically significant when I suspect the ECDFs aren't all that different and another set is returning not statistically significant when I feel like they are. I think this is due to the supremum of difference used in KS whereas I'm looking at area difference between the two curves. Is there a test that compares two ECDFs but only using area instead of supremum of difference?

Comment: Check out the Cramer von Mises and Anderson-Darling statistics.